# Display SMS send messages in listview android Studio

Tags: android

> I want to display in listview all sent sms messages from my device, currently I only managed to display all received messages in listview. Do you have any solution on how to do it? below is my current code, Thanks in advance to your response.

```
 ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

 public void displaymessage(){
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = cResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,"date");
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    do{
       String str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) ;
       arrayAdapter.add(str);
    }while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: If you mean that you want just the sent messages, change `"content://sms/inbox"` to `"content://sms/sent"`. If you want everything that you're allowed to read from the Provider – which is only the inbox and sent messages for non-default apps, since Marshmallow – you can use `"content://sms"`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are several SMS-related constants available in the SDK that you could use to replace most of those magic `String` literals. They're under [`android.provider.Telephony.Sms`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms). For example, you could replace `Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")` with `Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI`, and `Uri.parse("content://sms/sent")` with `Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI`, etc. The column names are available, too; e.g., `"address"` -> `Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS`, `"body"` -> `Telephony.Sms.BODY`, etc. Just FYI. Cheers!